# Broken zsh with chmod; trying to fix with compaudit

Tags: macos, zsh, osx-yosemite, homebrew, oh-my-zsh

I have Homebrew zsh as my shell. I don't have root on my machine, but I do have an additional account with elevated privileges -- this is just how it's been set up by my work and I can't do anything about it -- where I can sudo some things and install with Homebrew, etc.

Anyway, because of these conflicting accounts, I was having trouble getting other Homebrew'd stuff to work because of permission problems. So I did this:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw /usr/local
```

Now that fixed my immediate problem, but consequently it's broken my shell. Every time I start a new session, I get the following (which comes from the `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` line in my `.zshrc`):

```
compdef: unknown command or service: git
compdef: unknown command or service: git
```

...followed by the prompt. Moreover, tab completion no longer works. Other plugins are however working.

I have tried undoing my reckless `chmod` and following the guidance of using `compaudit` (e.g., see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762280/zsh-compinit-insecure-directories)), but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Out of desperation, I also tried completely uninstall-and-reinstalling zsh from Homebrew. This seems to have changed the output of `compaudit`, such that it now also contains a lot of things from `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.2/share/zsh/functions`. However, as far as I can see, everything here (including said directory) has the correct ownership (`my_admin:admin`) and permissions (`0744`). Similarly, the other things that `compaudit` is complaining about seem fine.

So I'm a bit stuck! What do I try next?

---

**UPDATE** So I tried this:

```
sudo chmod -R MODE /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.2/share/zsh
```

...where I've tried `MODE`s of `0777`, `0744`, `0754` and `0550`.

The first gives the original problem -- with the caveat that some plugin is causing all keyboard input to fail -- the rest (i.e., restricted access for non-owners) cause a number of zsh/Oh My Zsh definitions to not load and then cause subsequent errors when Oh My Zsh tries to load plugins. Specifically, it complains about `colors`, `compinit` and `compdef` being no longer defined (similarly, if I try `compaudit`, it fails).

I'm completely lost as to what's going on/why permission settings should be causing so much havoc. I'm going to stop experimenting, before I lock myself out completely, but if anyone's got suggestions on how to resolve this, they'd be most welcome!

Comment: Cross-posted to OMZ's GitHub issues: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/5442

Comment: I just started getting something similar. Have you found a fix?

Comment: @Marcel The problem was that my managed(ish) laptop has a superuser account (that isn't root) under which I have to install everything; however, my regular user account is what needs to use that software. When I installed Oh My Zsh with Homebrew, it set the owner of `/usr/local/share/zsh/whatever` to the superuser account. If I recursively reset the user to my regular account, it fixes the problem: `chown -R real_user /usr/local/share/zsh/whatever`... It's kind of an exotic setup, so it might not work for you.

Comment: I have now done `chmod 777 /usr/share/zsh -R` and `chown user:users /usr/share/zsh -R` and I am still getting issues. However, `sudo zsh` is working fine. I am so confused.